# Ambiguity of types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
_foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b  
_foldr op z [] = z
_foldr op z (x:xs) = x  `op` _foldr op z xs
```

Hi, let's consider above code.
After:

```
ghci> _foldr + 0 [1]
```

I got error:

```
   No instance for (Num t0) arising from the literal `1'
    The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus three others
```

Basically I understand  what it means and I suppose that changing of signature of function can repair that.

But, I don't want change a signature. How to solve it in another way?

Comment: You mean `_foldr (+) 0 [1]`? Also you are missing the pattern for when the list passed is empty. Also you keep padding `z` around ignoring the result of `(op)`. That function seems to always return the accumulator you passed.

Comment: the error there is just because of the `+` vs `(+)` problem Shoe mentioned - the other part would have bitten you at runtime

Comment: of course it is - you still have `_foldr + ` instead of  `_foldr (+)`! - if you want to pass an operator as a function you have to wrap it in `(..)` - just like you can make a function into an operator by writing ``x `op` ..`` (as you did now)

Comment: Thank you, you alright. But, I can't understand why:
_foldr op z (x:xs) = x  `op` _foldr op z xs is correct and why
_foldr op z (x:xs) = x  op _foldr op z xs is not correct

Comment: Haskell has two kind of names: operators (like `+`, `*`, `%` etc.) and `other_names`.  Operators are considered infix by default and you must use sections, i.e. `(+)`, to use them in prefix form. The `other_names` do the opposite: by default they are considered prefix and you use backticks as in ```​`op`​``` to make them prefix. So `f op z` is parsed as a call to `f` with two arguments `op` and `z`, while ```f `op` z``` is parsed as operator ```​`op`​``` apply to two arguments `f` and `z`.  Conversely for `+`: `f + z` is parsed as `+` applied to `f` and `z` while `f (+) z` is a call to `f`.

Comment: (If you are asking how I typed the backticks-inside backs in the comment above note that you can use triple backticks for inline code that contains backticks, however if you have a piece of code that starts with a backtick (thus you'd have 4 backticks in a row) you must add something in-between such as a zero-width unicode 0x200b character. a normal space doesn't seem to work.)

Comment: @Bakuriu it works with two backticks at the start too - you basically have to start with more backticks than you want to display ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whether your _foldr method does what you want, you can fix the issue in the question (no instance for (Num t0)), not by changing the signature of your function (you're right, this function can stay polymorphic), but by specifying what type you want to use for the call in GHCi. GHCi doesn't know what Num type you want when you typed `1`; do you want integers, or double? So you can annotate the 1 with a type to indicate, something like

```
_foldr (+) 0 [1::Int]
```

To work with Ints, for example.

Comment: What fixed the error was adding parentheses around `+`, not adding the `::Int`. `_foldr (+) 0 [1]` works fine.